# How do I add another check condition in this statement C# asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, if-statement, conditional-statements, refactoring

I have three case like this

1. When the user first sign in I will validate their request session id to build the cookie
2. When the user is already authenticated (previously signedin), I will validate the sessionId from their claim.

However there is another 2 case that comes up

3. When the user is already authenticated (previously signedin), do a certain activity, that can potentially prompt a change in their session Id, now if I validate with the session Id from their claim it will be wrong so I have to detect if there is a change between the claimSessionId and the requestSessionId => validate their requestSessionId.
4. After the user signed in some request performed by the user won't  send the requestSessionId hence the requestSessionId is empty, then in that case we will take the claimSessionId. This should be the last case though. How do you suggest we handle that as well?

```
var sessionToValidate = !UserPreviouslySignedIn() 
                ? GetRequestSessionId()
                : GetClaimSessionId();

await ValidateUserRequest(context, sessionToValidate);
```

How do I apply the check condition that a user may previously signed in but if sessionId != claimId then validate sessionid to this block of code and not having a bunch of if condition?

Comment: It helps if you write this out with traditional a `if-else-elseif` first. After doing that, you can easily translate it to the conditional assignment operator; but the question becomes should you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then my honest opinion, you're trying to do too much at once, and that will confuse other developers (us here at SO included) when they review or maintain your code. Keep it simple:

```
sessionToValidate = null;
if (!UserPreviouslySignedIn())
    sessionToValidate = GetRequestSessionId();
else {
    if (GetRequestSessionId() != GetClaimSessionId())
        sessionToValidate = GetRequestSessionId();
    else
        sessionToValidate = GetClaimSessionId();
}
```

To simplify this and make it easier to follow; your most common result is the request session ID as demonstrated above, so default to that:

```
var sessionToValidate = GetRequestSessionId();
```

Then, since your final condition requires the user to be logged in and the request ID to match the claim ID, then chain that together in a single check:

```
if (UserPreviouslySignedIn() && sessionToValidate == GetClaimSessionId())
    sessionToValidate = GetClaimSessionId();
```

This results in simpler code:

```
var sessionToValidate = GetRequestSessionId();
if (UserPreviouslySignedIn() && sessionToValidate == GetClaimSessionId())
    sessionToValidate = GetClaimSessionId();
```

---

Per your original request, this *can* be implemented using the conditional assignment operator:

```
sessionToValidate = !UserPreviouslySignedIn() ? GetRequestSessionId() :
                    GetRequestSessionId() != GetClaimSessionId() ? GetRequestSessionId() :
                                                                   GetClaimSessionId();
```

However, due to issues with readability, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Are you perhaps mix up this part where if If the userPreviouslySignedIn and sessionID do not match I have to GetRequestSessionId( )?

Comment: @Noelia updated; whether the user is signed in or not, you validate the request ID; *unless*, the request ID doesn't match the claim ID. As a result, you can default to the request ID and if the user is logged in and the request ID and claim ID match then you swap to validating the claim ID instead.

Comment: I was testing this and everything seems to be going well. However, there are some request after user has been signedIn that does not send the requestSessionId hence the requestSessionId is empty, then in that case we will take the claimSessionId. This should be the last case though. How do you suggest we handle that as well?

Comment: @Noelia Check if it's empty with an `or-else` operator: `if (UserPreviouslySignedIn() && (sessionToValidate == empty || sessionToValidate == GetClaimSessionId()))`

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, don't forget you can upvote and mark it as the answer to your question using the arrows and checkmark :)

Comment: Thank you it totally solves my problem. Now I just have to refactor the or condition to make it more readable.